# Understanding Ember Routes and Models

Tags: ember.js

I try to understand how Ember works and I have an issue I can't understand. I am following a tutorial (guides.emberjs.com/v1.10.0/) and I don't understand why I only see an element when I go on a page when I click (and doesn't work with a direct link).

I think some screenshots will be helpful to understand my issue.

This is what I have when I visit "*index.html#/posts/1*". No article is displayed.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/qzwlq.png

This is what I have when I visit "*index.html#/posts*" and then click on *Rails is Omakase* on the left. An article is displayed whereas the link is on my browser is "*index.html#/posts/1*" (and when I refresh nothing is displayed).

https://i.stack.imgur.com/YpmzX.png

This is my *index.html*

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Blog tuto</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap-combined.no-icons.min.css">
</head>
<body>
  <script type="text/x-handlebars">
    <div class="navbar">
      <div class="navbar-inner">
        <a class="brand" href="#">Bloggr</a>
        <ul class="nav">
          <li>{{#link-to "posts.index"}}Posts{{/link-to}}</li>
          <li>{{#link-to "about"}}About{{/link-to}}</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    {{outlet}}
  </script>

  <script type="text/x-handlebars" id="about">
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum about
    </p>
  </script>

  <script type="text/x-handlebars" id="posts">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span4">
          <table class="table">
            <thead>
              <tr><th>Recent Posts</th></tr>
            </thead>
            {{#each post in model}}
            <tr>
              {{#link-to "posts.post" post}}
              <td>{{post.title}} <small class="muted">by {{post.author}}</small></td>
              {{/link-to}}
            </tr>
            {{/each}}
          </table>
        </div>
        <div class="span8">
          {{outlet}}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </script>

  <script type="text/x-handlebars" id="posts/post">
    {{#if isEditing}}
      {{partial "post/edit"}}
      <button {{action "doneEditing"}}>Done</button>
    {{else}}
      <button {{action "edit"}}>Edit</button>
    {{/if}}
    <h1>{{title}}</h1>
    <h2><small class="muted">by {{author}}</small></h2>
    <hr>
    <div class="intro">
      {{exerpt}}
    </div>
    <div class="below-the-fold">
      {{body}}
    </div>
  </script>

  <script type="text/x-handlebars" id="post/edit">
    <p>{{input type="text" value=title}}</p>
    <p>{{input type="text" value=exerpt}}</p>
    <p>{{textarea value=body}}</p>
  </script>

  <script src="../js/libs/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="../js/libs/handlebars.js"></script>
  <script src="../js/libs/ember.js"></script>
  <script src="../js/libs/ember-data.js"></script>
  <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/showdown/0.3.1/showdown.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.1.0/moment.min.js"></script>

  <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

And *app.js*

```
App = Ember.Application.create();

App.Router.map(function() {
    this.route('about');
    this.resource('posts', function () {
        this.route('post', {path: ':post_id'});
    });

});

App.PostsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function () {
        return posts;
    }
});

App.PostsPostRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function (params) {
        return posts.findBy('id', params.post_id);
    }
});

App.PostsPostController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    isEditing: false,

    actions: {
        edit: function () {
            this.set('isEditing', true);
        },
        doneEditing: function () {
            this.set('isEditing', false);
        }
    }
});


var posts = [{
    id: 1,
    title: "Rails is Omakase",
    author: "mc100s",
    date: new Date('08-06-2015'),
    exerpt: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet",
    body: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."
}, {
    id: 2,
    title: "The Parley Letter",
    author: "mc100s",
    date: new Date('08-06-2015'),
    exerpt: "Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit",
    body: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."
}];
```

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you click link, model is passed directly to the route and route's `model` hook is not fired, so you see article. When you reload route `model` hook is fired and something goes wrong.

Make string `id`, because params.post_id is String.

`findBy` is Ember.Array method. http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Array.html#method_findBy
I would try:

```
var posts = Ember.A([{
  // as is
}]);
```

Next change ObjectController to Controller (ObjectController is deprecated) and use {{model.title}} instead of {{title}} in template:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="posts/post">
  {{#if isEditing}}
    {{partial "post/edit"}}
    <button {{action "doneEditing"}}>Done</button>
  {{else}}
    <button {{action "edit"}}>Edit</button>
  {{/if}}
  <h1>{{model.title}}</h1>
  <h2><small class="muted">by {{model.author}}</small></h2>
  <hr>
  <div class="intro">
    {{model.exerpt}}
  </div>
  <div class="below-the-fold">
    {{model.body}}
  </div>
```

working jsbin here: http://jsbin.com/pozabixeka/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Thanks for the advice. But it doesn't change anything in my issue.

Comment: I've updated answer. use {{model.title}} instead of {{title}}

Comment: It is still the same.Maybe it is because there is nothing in the Data part in Ember Console

Comment: Next: 1) make string `id`, because `params.post_id` is String. 2) change ObjectController to Controller (ObjectController is deprecated)
I reproduce your code here http://jsbin.com/misolukadi/1/edit?html,js

Comment: If I just change `params.post_id` by `parseInt(params.post_id)` and it works. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Usually ember-data is using for models with string ids by default. So parseInt(params.id) is almost never used in ember apps. Thanks for patience.